# converting object types columns into numeric type using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I am trying to clean the data using pandas. When I execute df.datatypes it shows that the columns are of type objects. I wish to convert them into numeric types.
I tried various ways of doing so like;

```
data[['a','b']] = data[['a','b']].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors ='ignore')
```

Then,

```
data['c'] = data['c'].infer_objects()
```

But nothing seems to be working. The interpreter does not throw any error but at the same time, it does not performs the desired conversion.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanking in advance.

Comment: How's your data, what is your desired conversion? What's the current output ?

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar Yes tried but no conversion

Comment: did you assign the value to column like `df['col']=df['col'].astype('int')` ?

Comment: @ Dark Data is in excel sheet and columns have string and integer values including positive and negative numbers.   Columns types is object, I wish to hae numeric types

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar I gives error saying                                          ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'

Comment: @DhvaniShah a sample of what you are getting and what you want to get would be better to understand the case.

Comment: can you show us your data? and also result of `data.dtypes`

Comment: [Dataset](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cdMXNOziMkfnL7AJ3ZJ8Pi6vLqSLYy8g)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the help page of `to_numeric`, the description for `errors` is as follows:

```
errors : {'ignore', 'raise', 'coerce'}, default 'raise'
        - If 'raise', then invalid parsing will raise an exception
        - If 'coerce', then invalid parsing will be set as NaN
        - If 'ignore', then invalid parsing will return the input
```

If your `apply` returns your input without doing anything to it, then the reason is because you've non-convertible objects, and calling `to_numeric` with `errors='ignore'` isn't helping.

Try using the second option, `errors='coerce'`.

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

Or,

```
for c in df.columns:
    df[c] = pd.to_numeric(df[c], errors='coerce')
```

Also, `infer_objects` performs soft type-casting. If you want to check column dtypes, use `df.dtypes` instead.

Comment: @Dark Thanks for the heads up, that was a typo!

Comment: This might be it. Curious to know what OP is getting

Comment: for c in ['a', 'b']:
    df[c] = pd.to_numeric(df[c], errors='coerce')                                                                                                This worked only for few columns. For the rest of the columns, dtypes is object

Comment: @DhvaniShah That means you didn't iterate over all those columns. Uh, try `for c in df.columns: df[c] = pd.to_numeric(df[c], errors='coerce') `.

Comment: No. I did iterate the column list but it performed conversion only for 3 columns.

Comment: @DhvaniShah Unfortunately, I don't possess psychic powers... so I'd need to see your _real_ data to understand what is happening. Your code would also help.

Comment: Hey, I did a very silly mistake. It worked fine. Thanks a lot @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Comment: @DhvaniShah Thought so, ;) Happy coding.